# Keras CNN fits or does not fit train data based on random seed

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I was noticing some unstable behavior with a CNN model I am developing in Keras and was finally able to figure out that this was a function of the random seed.  Depending on the seed, I either get some training and fit or no learning and no fit on the training data.

Some more details on the modeling:
The "images" are not real images, but computed transforms of a custom data set.  The CNN is a mini Inception-like architecture.  The output is a regression, so I use a custom scaled sigmoid activation function at the end.

My images are precomputed and pre-augmented, so I wrote my own little batch generator to go through these in random order.  I've wondered if this has something to do with the problem, but from my basic debugging (printing which image indices are being returned) I can't see anything obviously wrong.

```
Environment:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Python: 3.7.3
Keras: 2.2.4
Tensorflow: 1.13.1
```

```py
## custom batch generator
def generate_batches(x, y, batch_size, shuffle=True):
    data_size = x.shape[0]
    indices = np.array(range(0, data_size))
    while True:
        if (shuffle == True):
            np.random.shuffle(indices)
        for start in range(0, data_size, batch_size):
            end = start + min(batch_size, data_size - start)
            batch_features = x[indices[start:end], :, :, :]
            batch_values = y[indices[start:end]]
            yield batch_features, batch_values

## return a value in the range of (3.0, 9.5)
def scaledSigmoid(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(x) * (9.5 - 3.0)) + 3.0



# for debugging:
np.random.seed(1)
rn.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)

# Training data shape: (23670, 70, 70, 4)
# Testing data shape: (250, 70, 70, 4)

## initialize the output bias to the mean of the training Y value
mean_y_train = np.mean(Y_train)
bias_init = keras.initializers.Constant(value=mean_y_train)

## set up the model
input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]
input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
steps_per_epoch = ceil(len(Y_train)/batch_size)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=5, min_lr=1e-6, verbose=0)
generator = generate_batches(X_train, Y_train, batch_size, shuffle=True)
# 'get_model_for_params' is not shown here
model = get_model_for_params(input_img, bias_init, dpr, d1, d2, lrate)

# run the model
history = model.fit_generator(generator, 
                              steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                              epochs=epochs, 
                              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
                              callbacks=[reduce_lr],
                              verbose=1)
```

I'm attaching two sets of plots here.  Plotting the learning history (loss/epoch) shows that with random seeds 1, 3, and 4 I see learning over time (not great, but good enough for now), but with random seeds 2, 5, and 6, after the first initial drop (bias adjustment?) there is no learning.   Plotting the predicted vs the actual regression values shows an OK fit for seeds 1, 3, and 4.  But for seeds 2, 5, and 6 the predicted values are all equal to the minimum value of my scaled sigmoid activation function.

[learning history plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO5o7.png)
[model prediction plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayF3e.png)

Comment: how is the data quality ? is it biased ? or random noises ?

Comment: How would you define data quality and noise in this case? When I am able to get a good fit, the residuals are very roughly Gaussian though there are deviations at the extremes.

Comment: For splitting dataset please follow stratified splitting. It ensured the train and test sets have approximately the same percentage of samples of each target class as the complete set.